# Updating AD User information

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, c#-4.0, active-directory

I am having a problem updating user information in an Active Directory DB...

When I run the following code I get this error:

> The specified directory service attribute or value does not exist

The problem is the path it is using to save the information is this:

```
CN=AD Test,OU=Container Name,DC=us,DC=flg,DC=int
```

`Ad Test` is the username in AD that I am trying to update.

and I believe it should be:

```
CN=Ad Test,OU=Container Name, OU=Server Name,DC=us,DC=flg,DC=int
```

I am new to Directory services so I would greatly appreciate any help in finding out why I cannot update... Thank you in advance

```
public bool UpdateActiveDirectory(string LdapServerName, string CustId, Employee SQLresult)
{
    try  
    {
        DirectoryEntry rootEntry = new DirectoryEntry("LDAP://" + LdapServerName, "usrename", "password", AuthenticationTypes.Secure);

        DirectorySearcher searcher = new DirectorySearcher(rootEntry); 
        searcher.Filter = "(sAMAccountName=" + SQLresult.LogonNT + ")";
        searcher.PropertiesToLoad.Add("title");
        searcher.PropertiesToLoad.Add("street");
        searcher.PropertiesToLoad.Add("1");
        searcher.PropertiesToLoad.Add("st");
        searcher.PropertiesToLoad.Add("postalCode");
        searcher.PropertiesToLoad.Add("department");
        searcher.PropertiesToLoad.Add("mail");
        searcher.PropertiesToLoad.Add("manager");
        searcher.PropertiesToLoad.Add("telephoneNumber");

        SearchResult result = searcher.FindOne();

        if (result != null)
        {
            // create new object from search result    
            DirectoryEntry entryToUpdate = result.GetDirectoryEntry();

            entryToUpdate.Properties["title"].Value = SQLresult.Title;
            entryToUpdate.Properties["street"].Value = SQLresult.Address;
            entryToUpdate.Properties["1"].Value = SQLresult.City;
            entryToUpdate.Properties["st"].Value = SQLresult.State;
            entryToUpdate.Properties["postalCode"].Value = SQLresult.ZipCode;
            entryToUpdate.Properties["department"].Value = SQLresult.Department;
            entryToUpdate.Properties["mail"].Value = SQLresult.EMailID;
            entryToUpdate.Properties["manager"].Value = SQLresult.ManagerName;
            entryToUpdate.Properties["telephoneNumber"].Value = SQLresult.Phone;

            entryToUpdate.CommitChanges();

            Console.WriteLine("User Updated");
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("User not found!");
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Exception caught:\n\n" + e.ToString());
    } 

    return true;
}
```

Comment: Maybe just a typo? The third property you're trying to update: `entryToUpdate.Properties["1"].Value = SQLresult.City;` - is that a *one* (`1`) in there? It should be a small `L` (`l`) instead. Also: the manager's name must be the **Distinguished Name** of the manager - the whole `CN=Manager,CN=Ad Test,OU=Container Name, OU=Server Name,DC=us,DC=flg,DC=int` thing - not just the name itself.

Comment: If that doesn't help anything - just go back to old-school debugging technique: update just a **single** property - if it fails --> that's your problem case - figure out *why* it's a problem. If it works: uncomment a second property and run again -> repeat over and over again, until you find your culprit

Comment: Thank You marc_s ... That solved that issue ... I am getting a different error when I try to commit the changes it says: "Access Denied." I thought it would use the credentials that I passed in originally. How would i use them during the commit?

Comment: Maybe the credentials you're using are only allowed to *read* from Active Directory ...

Comment: The user account didn't have the correct permissions to save. Thank You for the help...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Maybe just a typo?

The third property you're trying to update:

```
entryToUpdate.Properties["1"].Value = SQLresult.City;
```

is that a one (`1`) in there? It should be a small L (`l`) instead.

Also: the manager's name must be the Distinguished Name of the manager - the whole

```
CN=Manager,CN=Ad Test,OU=Container Name, OU=Server Name,DC=us,DC=flg,DC=int
```

thing - not just the name itself.

If that doesn't help anything - just go back to old-school debugging technique:

- update just a single property; if it fails --> that's your problem case - figure out why it's a problem.
- If it works: uncomment a second property and run again

-> repeat over and over again, until you find your culprit

Comment: This was the key for me: **Also: the manager's name must be the Distinguished Name** Thanks!